# Excel Macro able to save csv on Win8.1 but stopped saving / working on Win10

Tags: windows, vba, excel, csv

How can i modify the below VBA code to make it work on Win10? It works fine on Win8.1. On my Win10 computer, it creates directory but is unable to save csv.

This code is additional part i myself wrote add saving csv functionality to data-fetching code (source: http://investexcel.net ).

Below is the error message I received while running entire macro (after making  Application.DisplayAlerts = True)

> '16.csdv' cannot be accessed. The file may be corrupted, located on a server that is not responding, or read-only.  (Options - Retry / Cancel)

After pressing cancel got this error:

> Run-time error 1004: Application defined or object defined error

Pressing debug takes me to this part of code (highlighted in yellow)

```
    ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:=FName, _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

This the whole code body that saves CSV.

```
Dim strName As String
Dim strDirname, Path, strDefpath As String
Dim FName As String

On Error Resume Next ' If directory exist goto next line

'Now we check if export folder exists. If not then it gets created here


If Len(Dir("Z:\MyBackfill\Extracts\", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
MkDir "Z:\MyBackfill\Extracts\"
End If

strDirname = Format(CStr(Now), "DDMMMYY") ' New directory name
strDefpath = "Z:\MyBackfill\Extracts\"
MkDir strDefpath & strDirname
Path = strDefpath & strDirname & "\"  'create total string
dt = Format(CStr(Now), "DDMMMYY HHMMSS")



Worksheets("Data").Activate
Range("G8").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss"
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("G:G").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False


With ActiveSheet

 lLastRow = .Columns("G:G").Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 ReDim arrDate(1 To lLastRow) As Long
 ReDim arrTime(1 To lLastRow) As Double
 arrDateTimes = .Range("G1:G" & lLastRow).Value
 For lRow = LBound(arrDateTimes) To UBound(arrDateTimes)
 arrDate(lRow) = Int(arrDateTimes(lRow, 1))
 arrTime(lRow) = arrDateTimes(lRow, 1) - arrDate(lRow)
 Next
 .Range("H1:H" & lLastRow).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrDate)
 .Range("I1:I" & lLastRow).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrTime)
 .Range("H1:H" & lLastRow).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yy"
 .Range("I1:I" & lLastRow).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"

 End With


 ' Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("G1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
 '    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
 '   Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo:= _
  '  Array(1, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


 Range("G8").Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
 Selection.NumberFormat = "dd-MM-yy"
 Range("H8").Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
 Selection.NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

 Columns("H:I").Select
 Selection.Cut
 Columns("B:B").Select
 Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

Columns("Z:I").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Range("B8").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd-MM-yy"
Range("C8").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"


Range("A8").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Parameters!R[5]C[1]"
Range("A8").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A8").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A8:A4520")
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A8:A" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
'Range("A8:A4520").Select
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("H:H").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Rows("1:7").Select
Range("A7").Activate
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp


'ADDING 59 to Seconds for correct backfill//////////////////////////////////////////
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlDown))
cell.Value = Left$(cell.Value, 6) & "59"
Next




'Filename = "GFill" & " " & DataSheet.Range("A1").Value & " " & dt & " " & "FROM" & "_" & DataSheet.Range("B1").Value & ".csv"
Filename = "GFill" & " " & "NIFTY" & " " & dt & " " & "FROM" & "_" & DataSheet.Range("B1").Value & ".csv"
FName = Path & Filename


Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'ChDir "C:\Users\Vaibhav\Desktop"
ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:=FName, _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
Selection.QueryTable.Delete
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? If so, where?

Comment: Sorry, adding the error line to main question body now. Please do check in a  moment.

Comment: Well, you're using Select and Selection methods and the Active objects so anything could be happening.  If you want reliable excel VBA macros stop using these crutches and start using range objects and methods, and object variables instead.

Comment: Below is the error message I received while running entire macro (after making  Application.DisplayAlerts = True)

> '16.csdv' cannot be accessed. The file may be corrupted, located on a server that is not responding, or read-only.  (Options - Retry / Cancel)

Comment: RBarryYoung, thanks but, I don't know how to use all that. Please note that this was working fine until recently. And still does work fine on Win8.1

Comment: Get rid of `On Error Resume Next`...

Comment: David now it's giving run-time error 75 - "Path/File Access Error"

Comment: And *which line* raises the error?

Comment: MkDir strDefpath & strDirname

Comment: Then your Win 10 PC does not have write access to the Z share.

Comment: Using `On Error Resume Next` is generally not recommended, because all it does is *hide* errors, and proceed to the next line, which often means that one error contributes to additional errors and incorrect output, etc, and makes your troubleshooting very difficult...

Comment: I can't agree more. Then it is an issue with Win10. Because I get no such error on Win8.1 Not that I tried looking for errors. But this macro saves csv. Which means can't have access error.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to be an OS issue, it seems to be a machine/permission issue. If your Win10 machine doesn't have write-access to the Z drive, this error is expected, and it's not the fault of the OS, it's the fault of your profile/group policy/drive permissions/etc.

Comment: Now how do I ensure that excel gets the right to save files? Any ideas? If there's a Win10 policy that could be changed.. or anything else?

Comment: But it didn't save on E drive as well.

Comment: That's not something that can be solved with VBA, that's a question for your IT Help Desk or administrators... It may be as simple as "you're not mapped to the drive" (or your mapped to that drive, but as a different letter, etc.)

Comment: Does it save to "C" drive?

Comment: Checking about C in a moment

Comment: same error for c drive as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116098/discussion-between-david-zemens-and-vaibhav).

Comment: Please have a look again at the main question body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of tricky.

The `MkDir` function cannot create a `Drive:\Directory\Subdirectory` all at once -- it's attempting to create the subdirectory in a directory which doesn't exist, so you first have to create the directory, and *then* you can use it to create the subdirectory:

```
MkDir "Drive:\Directory"
MkDir "Drive:\Directory\Subdirectory"
```

So this most likely explains why you're getting a failure even on the C drive of your Win10 machine.

Regarding the Z & E drives (assuming those are Shares) then a similar error would occur if you don't have permission to access or write those drives, from the Win10 machine; that is not a problem that can be resolved with VBA, unless it is a simple drive-letter mapping issue, in which case you can probably resolve it by providing the full canonical path, e.g.:

```
MkDir "\\servername\Directory"
```

As you're still getting an error on SaveAs, examine the value of `Fname`.

You're pulling in a Date value from:

`DataSheet.Range("B1").Value`

And this includes forward slash characters which can't be used in a file name.

Try instead:

`Format(DataSheet.Range("B1").Value, "yyyymmdd")`

Comment: I have 2 pcs and running the macro locally on both. Pc1 has win8.1 and pc2 has win10. I have ensured that all directories are in place already. Only the final directory is created when macro is executed. That final directory is named as current date.

Also, the macro is creating that final folder named {current date}. Only the file is not saved

Comment: So it's failing now only at `ActiveSheet.SaveAs...`?  What's the value of `FName`?

Comment: `strDirname = Format(CStr(Now), "DDMMMYY") ' New directory name`
`strDefpath = "C:\MyBackfill\Extracts\"`
`MkDir strDefpath & strDirname`
`Path = strDefpath & strDirname & "\"  'create total string`
`Filename = "GFill" & " " & "NIFTY" & " " & dt & " " & "FROM" & "_" & DataSheet.Range("B1").Value & ".csv"`
`FName = Path & Filename `

Comment: No. Please show what is the *actual value* of the variable `FName`. I can clearly see how it's being constructed, but I want to see what it *is* when the error occurs.

Comment: I don't know how to find Fname when it is being created. Ideally it is the complete path where file is saved + GFill + space + Nifty + space + date + from ....

However, it seems excel is trying to save it as 16.csv

Does this answer your question?

Comment: No... you can see the value in the "Locals" window (View | Locals) or you can add a `Debug.Print Fname` statement on the line before `ActiveSheet.SaveAs`.  Or you can just do `?FName` in the "Immediate" window of the VBE...

Comment: This will save you hours of headaches: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: Is it possible for me to share the file with you so that you could please have a look?

Comment: Is it possible that you will pay my consulting rate? I'm doing this right now, free. If you want to start talking about sending me files and stuff, that's beyond what I'll do for free.

Comment: Sure, please do inform. I would like that.

Comment: Before you think about paying me $100/hour to look at your file, why don't you try to determine the value of that `FName` variable, when the error occurs. I've given you three ways to do this...

Comment: Debug.Print FName doesn't do anything. 
And ?FName doesn't return anything in immediate
In locals windows i get this
  : FName : "" : String

Comment: Run time error 75 - path/file access error comes before the debug.print could get executed

Comment: i used on error resume next and also msgbox. This is the FName value i got:
C:\MyBackFill\Extracts\30Jun16\GFill NIFTY 30Jun16 201438 FROM _10/06/16.csv

Comment: immediate window is showing this: C:\MyBackfill\Extracts\30Jun16\GFill NIFTY 30Jun16 201438 FROM_10/06/16.csv

because of "on error resume next" i guess

Comment: You've got forward slashes in the destination filename, these are not allowed (along with a few other special characters/punctuation). That will always raise an error

Comment: That's right. I just reached the same conclusion when i noticed it. Changed the FName variable suitable to remove those slashes and voila. File generated. any clues how to remove them in win10 settings? Obviously they dont come up in Win8.1

Comment: I don't have win 8 or win 10 but TBH I'm surprised it wouldn't error in win8... use the `Format` function on the date value (see my revised answer)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David Zemens.

He pointed me towards using immediate window.

The problem was coming up because for some reason "/" was coming up in filename and that shouldn't.

Suitably edited the FileName variable to remove the "/" and files are getting generated properly.

Just to note that this same issue is not coming up in win8.1